# Two questions about "wraparound" with "Event" method

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I am learning [EventLocator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) method from the document center. As for the following code (copy from this document) solving the *sine-Gordon* equation, it uses the `pseudospectral` method for the integration.

```
sgsol = First[NDSolve[
  {D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] - Sin[u[t, x]], 
   u[0, x] == E^(-(x - 5)^2) + E^(-(x + 5)^2/2), 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
   u[t, -50] == u[t, 50]
  }, 
  u, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, -50, 50}, 
  Method -> {
    "MethodOfLines", "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}, 
    Method -> {
      "EventLocator", "Event" :> Abs[First[u[t, x]]] - 0.01, 
      "EventLocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"
    }
  }
 ]
]
```

According to the document: Since no *absorbing layer* has been set near the boundaries, it is appropriate to stop integration once **wraparound**
becomes significant, which is detected with `EventLocator`. The integration is stopped when the size of the solution at the **wraparound** point crosses a threshold of 0.01.

For this explanation, I have two questions:

**(1)** What is the meaning of **wraparound**, or what is the intuitively numerical behavior of **wraparound**.

**(2)** It could be because that I don't understand **wraparound**, I do not know why one should stop integration when $|u[t, -50]|>0.01$. I noted that $u[t, -50]\neq0$ usually. My confusion is why we should restrict the boundary condition of `u[t, -50] == u[t, 50]` within a small value, i.e. 0.01?

Thank you!

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, now I understand it better, thanks for your example. It would be better if you delete the $\prime$ for `v` :)

Comment: A hyperbolic initial-value PDE in a large region can be solved in a smaller region, using periodic boundary conditions. An example is ripples on a pond caused by dropping a stone into it. The solution is correct, until ripples reach one boundary of the small region and reenter at the opposite boundary, where they interact with ripples propagating directly from where the stone was dropped. This behavior is called wraparound. A safe way to prevent wraparound is to terminate the computation at `t == x / v`, where `v` is the characteristic wave velocity, and `x` the characteristic distance